How do build a top component wrapper in next.js?
So I'm getting this error:  Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option
And the reason is because my component is not wrapped in ApolloProvider
So at my home page I have:
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Products />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

and this works fine, I make a query inside <Products /> all good
but I have a pages/product/[id].js page and this is where the issue is and it blows up here and I believe because this page lives outside of the component tree
historically (in CRA) the index entry point would render every thing but beneath but I can't see this concept in next.js
Surely the solution is not to wrap every subsequent page in <ApolloProvider client={client}> so how can I fix this, what is the correct next.js solution to this?

What about moving the provider into the root layout rather than in the page?

I could be wrong but that feels wrong? Wouldn't layouts be associated more with page styling/structure as opposed to wrapping with a functionality ?

Layouts in next are shared between pages. Pages aren’t shared. From what would’ve described you want to share the provider between multiple pages

every component that needs access to the apollo client needs the wrapper somewhere higher in the tree. For us this meant placing the wrapper in the _app.jsx, right next to a translation wrapper since all our components/pages potentially could use gql.

Consider putting it in the root layout? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout

@JWittmeyer could you expand that a little more? what imports _app.jsx? how does that get automatically loaded?

actually figured it out. was simple. thanks]

@RedBaron what did you end up doing?

Please use the official Apollo Client Next.js helper package. Next.js uses React features in a very specific way, and those require framework-specific extra code.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs
